# Ajax refreshes the whole page instead of a particular part

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Net web services. The following code is attached to my master page using a JS. When I run the ajax call, it seems like at the end of success function, it refreshes the whole page. Rather than some particular part. I have tried using both ways, form + input submit, and normal button with click function.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'service url',
        data: { LookupParameter: somevariable },
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'xml',
        asynch: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var xmldata = $(data);
            //dom manipulation code
        },
        error: function (e) {

        }
    });
```

Master Page 
following code is embedded inside body tag. but not in content placeholder.

```
<form itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness" id="form1" runat="server">
<span class="input-group-addon borderRadiusZero" id="basic-addon1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span>
</span>
<Input ID="txt_lookup_pincode" type="number" class="form-control" min="111111" max="999999" placeholder="Enter Your Pincode" />
<span class="input-group-btn ">
    <button id="LookupServicesa" class="btn btn-primary borderRadiusZero" onClick="HomeCheckDeliverableAreas();" style="height:100%;">Submit</button>
    <input id="LookupServices" class="btn btn-primary borderRadiusZero" style="height:100%;" type="submit" value="submitM" />
</span>
```

Comment: Add this code `location.reload();` in ajax success .

Comment: @purvik7373 The OP wants to *not* reload the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may be because of this line

```
<button id="LookupServicesa" class="btn btn-primary borderRadiusZero" onClick="HomeCheckDeliverableAreas();" style="height:100%;">Submit</button>
```

The `button type` is not defined here. In this case the default type that is `submit` will be applied.

Define the button type as button

```
<button type = "button" id="LookupServicesa" class="btn btn-primary borderRadiusZero" onClick="HomeCheckDeliverableAreas();" style="height:100%;">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your JavaScript function with the Ajax call is included in the `onclick` handler of your button, it should return false to prevent the default action of the button:

```
<button id="LookupServicesa" class="btn btn-primary borderRadiusZero" onClick="HomeCheckDeliverableAreas(); return false;" style="height:100%;">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the button the type "button" to suppress the default behavior

```
<button type="button" id="LookupServicesa" class="btn btn-primary borderRadiusZero" onClick="HomeCheckDeliverableAreas();" style="height:100%;">Submit</button
```

Answer (score 0):

put the dom elements which you want to refresh after the ajax success in another div which is outside the form and do the manipulations to that div. Hope this helps!